# Class with no constructor (implicit or explicit)

Tags: c++

As far as I know, you get an implicit default constructor if you do not declare any constructor yourself. As a job interview question I was asked for a situation where you do not declare a constructor but still do not get an implicit default constructor either. So you end up with a class without any constructors. It is supposed to be code that compiles, so the answer is not having a member variable that does itself not provide a default constructor. Any ideas? Searching through stack overflow and various C++ sites did not reveal anything. Also, as a hint the interviewer said it does not have to do with inheritance.

Comment: Off the top of my head...make it static? I'm not sure.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't declare a class to be static in C++.

Comment: @chris it's entirely possible that's the case, I haven't done any c++ developing in quite a while.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar, Well, C# et al. complicate things in that regard, as it's perfectly valid and does what you expect there.

Comment: Defining a class that has a base or member without default constructor does not cause a compilation error.  Attempting to use that class's default constructor would.

Comment: @chis - If all the methods and all the variables are static one can assume that the class is static (who want to do that is a different matter)

Answer (score 3):

If my reading of the standard is correct, if the default constructor is not used, it won't get implicitly defined.

C++11 12.1.6:

> A default constructor that is defaulted and not deﬁned as deleted is implicitly deﬁned when it is odr-used (3.2) to create an object of its class type (1.8) or when it is explicitly defaulted after its ﬁrst declaration.

Also, a default constructor can be defined as "deleted", C++11 12.1.5:

> A
>   defaulted default constructor for class X is deﬁned as deleted if:
>
> - X is a union-like class that has a variant member with a non-trivial default constructor,
> - any non-static data member with no brace-or-equal-initializer is of reference type,
> - any non-variant non-static data member of const-qualiﬁed type (or array thereof) with no brace-orequal-initializer does not have a user-provided default constructor,
> - X is a union and all of its variant members are of const-qualiﬁed type (or array thereof),
> - X is a non-union class and all members of any anonymous union member are of const-qualiﬁed type
>     (or array thereof), or
> - any direct or virtual base class, or non-static data member with no brace-or-equal-initializer, has class
>     type M (or array thereof) and either M has no default constructor or overload resolution (13.3) as applied
>     to M’s default constructor results in an ambiguity or in a function that is deleted or inaccessible from
>     the defaulted default constructor.

For example, it would appear from the above that the following program is well-formed:

```
struct X {
  X(int) {}
};

struct Y {
  X x;
};
```

Here `Y` does not have an implicitly defined default constructor because it's both not used and defined as deleted.

Comment: Interesting quotation. That really hides all of the "It must have one if we can create objects" behind the fact that it doesn't until we do.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such trick, unless it's a catch in the exact wording of the question.

12.1p5:

> If there is no user-declared constructor for class `X`, a constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted.

The implicitly declared default constructor might be defined as deleted, but it is still a member of the class.

Comment: I wish the standard was written in a more accessible language. We somehow reached the opposite conclusions by reading the same text, and I have no idea who is right. :-(

Comment: @NPE: The constructor can be selected by overload resolution without being odr-used, e.g. via `decltype`.  But I agree that the implicitly declared default constructor is not necessarily implicitly defined.

Answer (score 0):

Effective C++, Item 5: "These functions [ctor, dtor, copy ctor, copy assignment operator] are generated only if they are needed [...]"

According to that, if you have a class that has no declared ctors, and you do not create any instances of that class, then your class will have no constructor(s) at all.